# endless "for" loop in release configuration of iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have the following code in my application:

```
NSArray *lstAttributes = [conditionAttribute componentsSeparatedByString:cstrSystemUIConfigurationAttributeConditionSeparator],
    *lstValues = [conditionValue componentsSeparatedByString:cstrSystemUIConfigurationAttributeConditionSeparator],
    *lstValueTypes = [conditionValueType componentsSeparatedByString:cstrSystemUIConfigurationAttributeConditionSeparator];

if([lstAttributes count] != [lstValues count] ||
   [lstAttributes count] != [lstValueTypes count]) return NO;

BOOL bResult = YES;
NSLog(@"attributes amount - %u", [lstAttributes count]);
for(uint i = 0; i < [lstAttributes count]; i ++)
{
    NSLog(@"counter: %u", i);
    SystemUIConfigurationAttributeCondition *condition = [SystemUIConfigurationAttributeCondition new];

    condition.conditionAttribute = [lstAttributes objectAtIndex:i];
    condition.conditionValue = [lstValues objectAtIndex:i];
    condition.conditionValueType = [lstValueTypes objectAtIndex:i];

    bResult &= [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];

    FreeObject(&condition);

    if(!bResult) break;
}

return bResult;
```

everything is fine in "debug" configuration. but once i switch it to "release" i face the endless loop. console shows me the following: attributes amount - 2, counter: 0, counter: 1, counter: 1, counter: 1, counter: 1, counter: 1, counter: 1, ...... etc.

i tried to use different "for" and "while" operators, but nothing of that worked correctly. the loop still can't be stopped.

has anyone faced the same problem before?

Comment: I have had some oddities in objective-c - but none quite as strange as that.  I can only suggest tracing the value of i after every operation in the loop, so see whether its being decremented / reset to 0 somewhere in the loop.  If not then its an oddity with the for() statement itself

Comment: try commenting this out

bResult &= [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];

Comment: Have you tried: `for(int i = 0; i < [lstAttributes count]; i++) ...`

Comment: That's really strange. I'd comment out everything except the NSLog and lstAttributes assignment.  See if it still happens.  If it doesn't, then add each line back one at a time.

Comment: what is the name of the function? you might be "accidentally" using recursion

Comment: name of the function is:
"- (BOOL) checkConditionsForOwner:(id)owner". there is not recursion here, these functions are different at types and amount of parameters.

Comment: btw, if i comment out line 'bResult &= [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];' then it works...

Comment: Aha.  What data type is returned from `checkCondition:forOwner:`?  BOOL is a typedef for signed character.  Maybe the bitwise-and operation overruns bResult and stomps on your i variable under certain combinations of optimization and architecture.

Comment: yes, returned type is BOOL. i tried to change the code, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: You might be able to prove cduhn's theory by adding uint some_padding = 0xFFFF; under the declaration for bResult. That might protect "i" and you could send some_padding to the console output in the loop to see if changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround for this bug as promised:

at first i tried to use code blocks to enumerate all objects in a list instead of "for" loop.

```
__block BOOL bResult = YES;
[lstAttributes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    SystemUIConfigurationAttributeCondition *condition = [SystemUIConfigurationAttributeCondition new];

    condition.conditionAttribute = [lstAttributes objectAtIndex:idx];
    condition.conditionValue = [lstValues objectAtIndex:idx];
    condition.conditionValueType = [lstValueTypes objectAtIndex:idx];

    bResult &= [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];

    FreeObject(&condition);

    if(!bResult) *stop = YES;
}];
```

but i got a crash on second iteration. "lstValues" and "lstValueTypes" pointers suddenly changed their values and application received EXC_BAD_ACCESS. possibly usage of 3 arrays while enumerating only 1 of them is not a good idea. debugger shows that enumeration is performed on the same thread, but 2 of 3 arrays are corrupted by the moment of 2nd iteration.

so i decided to split up my initial loop into 2 parts:

1. prepare a list of conditions
2. check each condition.

first is a usual "for" loop, second - 'enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:" method of NSArray class. so the final code looks like:

```
NSArray *lstAttributes = [conditionAttribute componentsSeparatedByString:cstrSystemUIConfigurationAttributeConditionSeparator],
    *lstValues = [conditionValue componentsSeparatedByString:cstrSystemUIConfigurationAttributeConditionSeparator],
    *lstValueTypes = [conditionValueType componentsSeparatedByString:cstrSystemUIConfigurationAttributeConditionSeparator];

if([lstAttributes count] != [lstValues count] ||
   [lstAttributes count] != [lstValueTypes count]) return NO;

NSMutableArray *lstConditions = [NSMutableArray new];
for(uint i = 0; i < [lstAttributes count]; i ++)
{
    SystemUIConfigurationAttributeCondition *condition = [SystemUIConfigurationAttributeCondition new];

    condition.conditionAttribute = [lstAttributes objectAtIndex:i];
    condition.conditionValue = [lstValues objectAtIndex:i];
    condition.conditionValueType = [lstValueTypes objectAtIndex:i];

    [lstConditions addObject:condition];
    FreeObject(&condition);
}

__block BOOL bResult = YES;
[lstConditions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) 
{
    if([self checkCondition:[lstConditions objectAtIndex:i] forOwner:owner] == NO)
    {
        bResult = NO;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

FreeObject(&lstConditions);

return bResult;
```

this code works.

i would appreciate if anyone can explain the behavior of my initial loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention in your comments that it works if you comment out the &= operation, I'd change that line to:

```
bResult = bResult && [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];
```

This does a boolean AND, which is what you really intend to do on this line anyway.  &= does a bitwise AND, which isn't always equivalent to a boolean AND, since any nonzero value evaluates to true.  For example:

```
BOOL a = 1;
BOOL b = 2;

if (a && b) {
    NSLog (@"a && b is true"); // This line will execute
}
if (a & b) {
    NSLog (@"a & b is true");  // This line won't execute
}
```

Since it's common to use object addresses in our conditionals, using the bitwise AND in place of a boolean AND could create bugs.  For example, if you return an object address from `getCondition:fromOwner:`, intending it to mean YES, and that memory address happens to be an even number, then a bitwise AND with YES will evaluate to NO, where a boolean AND would evaluate to YES.

My best guess as to the cause of your specific bug is that the bitwise-AND is somehow causing a buffer overrun, which stomps on your i variable.  If that hypothesis is correct, then switching to a boolean AND should fix that too.

Comment: you are right, and i faced such bugs before. but currently problem lies not in this comparison (or it seems so). i tried it right after i wrote that code works without &= operation.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused.  You wrote "if i comment out line 'bResult &= [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];' then it works...".  I took that to mean that commenting out that line fixes your infinite loop.  So I'm suggesting that changing the line to use && instead of &= may also fix the infinite loop.  Are you saying that you tried using &&, and you still have the infinite loop?

Comment: yes, i still have infinite loop. i mean with either
"bResult &= [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];"
or
bResult = bResult && [self checkCondition:condition forOwner:owner];

Comment: i think i found a solution for this bug, but i can't answer my own question in 8 hours. so i have to wait until the morning.

Comment: Wow.  I'm really surprised that && didn't fix it but commenting out the line did.  I can't wait to find out what caused this.

Comment: and i still don't know the exact reason. i just found a work around. another interesting thing: there are several situations when some instructions are ignored at all. and i can't understand if it is caused by my debugging of release configuration (i mean, normally release app can't be debugged) or by optimization.

Comment: Does the infinite loop happen on both the device and the simulator?  I'd love to replicate this bug.  It's fascinating.

Comment: yes, it can be reproduced on both device and simulator. i'm not sure if it will be easy to reproduce. i have a lot of loops in the app, but only one causes such problems.